# Store last command in a variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm want to store the most recent command in a variable. I tried the `!!:p` history expansion, it does get me the last command but I can't store it in a variable.

```
$ last=`!!:p`
last=`ls`
$ echo $last

$
```

Any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `fc` command can be used to retrieve the previous command.

```
some_var=$(fc -nl -1)
```

Comment: This is not working when used inside a shell script to print the command ran in the previous line

Answer (score 2):

The solution [given above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715809/4424636) does not work inside a script file:

```
some_var=$(fc -nl -1)
```

What I did was use trap option and store the last command in environment variable before the script is called and access the env variable in script.

Add this function in `~/.bashrc`

```
function process_command() {
  if [ "$BASH_COMMAND" != "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ];then
    export myCMD=$BASH_COMMAND
  fi
}
trap process_command DEBUG
```

Then use `$myCMD` variable in any script or anywhere in shell.

Answer (score 1):

Using `!!:p` only prints the last command, to execute the last command you would do `!!`.

```
$ mycmd="$(!!)"
$ sh "$mycmd"
```

That should do what you're looking for...