# Store last bash command in bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have bash script file.

**last_command=$(!!);**

here variable last_command should have the value of last command executed but it is not..
i get this error: !!: command not found

I also tried this:
**Last_command=$(fc -nl -1)**

*This works in direct shell but when i try to use in bash script file it gives error.

Reference= [Store last command in a variable in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715729/linux-store-last-command-into-variable)

Comment: History expansion is not available everywhere. (It's also off-by-default in scripts, and generally a bad idea to rely on).

Comment: But when I simply execute !! in shell it does print last command

Comment: Is there some reason you actually want to store the result in `last_command` and jut just push the up-arrow key? (yes `!!` is available on the command line, just not in *Command Substitution*)

Comment: @Encycode, yes, your shell is interactive; it has features that aren't available in other contexts. History expansions like `!!` are similar to `ctrl+r` in that they're special interactive features (though not implemented quite at the same layer), as opposed to part of the shell's programming language.

Comment: I need to send last executed command to my APIs at remote end..I managed to trigger a bash script on every execution of command via PROMPT_COMMAND.. But i also need the value of last command

Comment: See the link up at the top of your question to the previously-asked copy of the same question? It has answers. Read and use them.

Comment: some_var=$(fc -nl -1) that solution is not working..

Comment: (BTW, history expansion is also not always available at all; personally, one of the very first things I do when setting up `.bashrc` on a new machine is add the command `set +H` to turn it off, thus avoiding some of the bits of bizarreness it adds to shell syntax, which is already bizarre enough without making characters like `!` and `^` need to be escaped in a subset of their use cases... but as I said before, _in a script_ it's off by default anyhow).

Comment: "Not working" isn't a very specific problem description, but if you were to write something that _was_ a specific question, [unix.se] would be a better place to ask it.

Comment: Try look at this answer it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912283/14031849

Comment: Please note that '!!' does not just print the last command.  It prints the command followed by the standard output of executing the command.